# Waiting for event silence

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I need to create a method for listening to events and waiting for a certain amount of silence before calling another function.

Specifically, I am listening to a directory for file updates. When a file change occurs, my "directoryUpdate" function is called. From there I add the file to a list and create a thread called "timerThread" which sleeps for 2 seconds. When that thread is done sleeping, it calls a "gatherFinished" function.

But since directoryUpdate gets called 10 times all at once if 10 files change, it would launch 10 threads which seems like a bad way of doing this.

In the end I want a list of the file changes that occurred within 2 seconds of each other. I figure if there is a way to reset the sleep time to 2 seconds every time a change occurs and wait for the 2 seconds to finish, then I will have what I need. But there is no way to reset the timer as far as I know.

What is the best way of doing this?

**UPDATE**
Thanks for all your great answers. I am sorry for putting emphasis on getting the list of files. The event (file change) should not matter. I meant to focus on making sure the call to "gatherFinished" happens once at the right time - 2 seconds after all events in question have stopped firing. My question is on the nature of waiting, not on the nature of files or collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use an AutoResetEvent and wait 2 seconds on it. If the event is triggered then you loop and wait another 2 seconds.

```
        AutoResetEvent resetTimer = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        ...

        private void TimerJob()
        {
            ...

            // The thread will sleep and loop until 
            // 2 seconds elapse without directory changes 
            while (resetTimer.WaitOne(2000)) {}

            ...
        }

        private void ResetTimer()
        {
            resetTimer.Set();
        }
```

NOTE: I didn't put any code to specify you how to synchronize the thread that will receive the directory changes and the timer thread. You will have to do that youself.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to add each updated file to a list along with a timestamp of when they were added. Then, when your 2-second Timer fires, you can check for any items in the list that have a timestamp older than the last time it fired.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Jono,
This is actually a really fun problem.

If I understand correctly you're using the FileSystemWatcher or some other similar object to monitor a folder.

Each time a file is added or changes, you receive an event.

Now the problem is that this event can be raised at relatively random times, and if you're trying to record all files which have been modified within 2 seconds of eachother, you're going to have many collections of objects.

What I would do is to create a `List<List<MyFileChangeClass>>` where `MyFileChangeClass` is whatever construct you use to track the information that changed.

When you handle the event for a file modification, create your new `MyFileChangeClass` with the necessary details and iterate the outer list.  For each list, check to see if the first `MyFileChangeClass` has a time stamp of less than 2 seconds before the current file modification, if so, add your file modification to the inner list.

Once you're done walking the entire list, add a new `List<MyFileChangeClass>` to the outer list, which is populated with only the current `MyFileChangeClass`.  This will ensure that future modifications can be associated with the latest one and that you have all groupings of modifications which occurred within 2 seconds of eachother.

Around the entire thing, I'd include a lock - probably a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` using `TryEnterWriteLock()`.

I hope this helps - if you need more details, please let me know, but obviously you know a bit about what you're doing and probably just needed a bit of logic help because it's a strange problem.

### Good luck!

Adam

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are using the `FileSystemWatcher` class to monitor for file system changes. Your problem is well suited for the producer-consumer pattern. In your case the producer is the `FileSystemWatcher` which will add changed files to a queue. The consumer will then dequeue the file names from the queue once they appear. The nice thing about this pattern is that there is only one worker thread involved and all file changes will be processed in the order they are received.

Here is some code to get you started.

```
public class Example
{
  private BlockingCollection<string> m_Queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

  public Example()
  {
    var thread = new Thread(Consumer);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
  }

  public void QueueChangedFile(string filePath)
  {
    m_Queue.Add(filePath);
  }

  private void Consumer()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      // The Take method blocks until an item appears in the queue.
      string filePath = m_Queue.Take();
      // Do whatever you need to do with the file here.
    }
  }
}
```

From the `FileSystemWatcher` event handlers you would call the `QueueChangedFile`. Add whatever code you think is necessary to process the file changes in the `Consume` method after the call to `Take`. You can make the logic as sophisticated as necessary. If you need to keep track of the time the changes occurred (so that you can later figure out which files were changed within 2 seconds of each other) then instead of having the queue hold a `string` you could create a simple class that stores both the file path and the change time and have the queue store that wrapper class instead.